# How can the range of dissolving spittle be increased?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, meldshaping

The soulmeld *dissolving spittle* (*Magic of Incarnum* 64–5) grants the meldshaper a ranged touch attack that has a range of 30 ft. Incarum and Spells, in part, says, "Soulmelds interact with spells and spells interact with soulmelds in the same way that a spell or a normal spell-like ability interacts with another spell or spell-like ability," and, "Spells, spell-like abilities, and magic items that could potentially affect soulmelds do affect soulmelds" (52).

Does this mean that if the incarnate wears *horizon goggles* (*Complete Mage* 133) (8,000 gp; 0 lbs.) the range of the soulmeld *dissolving spittle* is increased by 50%? Similarly, does this mean that the range of the soulmeld *dissolving spittle* is doubled up to 3/day if the incarnate employs the effect of a *least [metamagic rod](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#metamagic-rods) of enlarge* (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 236) (3,000 gp; 4 lbs.) while hawking a caustic loogie? In short…

- If these magic items *don't* increase the range of the soulmeld *dissolving spittle*, why don't they?
- If these magic items *do* increase range of the soulmeld *dissolving spittle*, are there other magic items—and I'm looking specifically for magic items here—that grant the soulmeld *dissolving spittle* even greater range increases *or* smaller range increases at a lower price?

---

***Note:*** [Jalas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104226/8610) (and his two familiars with whom [he](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95555/8610) [shares](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101258/8610) [soulmelds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101235/8610)) has reached level 10 in the campaign I run, the lone party member who's been through all three of [Keep on the Borderlands](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98708/8610), Assassin's Knot, *and 7/8s of the I-didn't-realize-it-was-this-epic-when-we-started-it* [Castle Amber](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22castle%20amber%22). *However, Jalas has become increasingly saddened by his inability to dissolve foes that are beyond 30 ft.*

Comment: lol. isnt that... two questions? ^^

Comment: @nijineko No, no, that's a valid criticism. However, I'm pretty sure the two questions are so tightly bound that I can get away with it in a lone question. (In truth, I *could* rephrase the question so that the question *assumes* that those magic items improve the range of *dissolving spittle* and *then* ask what *else* does the same thing,  leaving it to answers to refute the question's premise. Making it so answers needn't *interpret the question*, though, seemed a fairer ask.)

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Horizon Googles, according to Complete Mage p.133, it affects projectile weapons and thrown weapons *only* :

> **Horizon Goggles**
>   These lenses greatly increase your prowess with ranged
>   attacks, allowing you to accurately strike targets much farther
>   away than normal.
>   Description: These goggles feature small oval lenses in
>   a wire-thin frame. When worn, they are difficult (Spot DC
>   15) for others to notice.
>   The world seems particularly clear and three-dimensional
>   when viewed through the goggles, which glow faintly any
>   time you nock a bow or otherwise prepare to use a ranged
>   weapon.
>   Activation: Horizon goggles are active as long as they are
>   worn; they require no special action to activate.
>   Effect: Horizon goggles grant you the benefits of the Far
>   Shot feat (increases range increment of **projectile weapons**
>   by 50%, and of **thrown weapons** by 100%).

According to the definition of Dissolving Spittle, it's a ranged touch attack i.e. a completely distinct thing:

> DISSOLVING SPITTLE
>   Descriptors: Acid
>   Classes: Incarnate
>   Chakra: Throat
>   Saving Throw: None
>   Incarnum forms a metallic blue-green torc around your neck.
>   The ends of the torc resemble black or copper dragons facing each
>   other in front of your throat. A constant bitter taste fl oods your
>   mouth, but it seems to make the fl avor of certain foods more
>   enjoyable—particularly well-cooked meat.
>   The infamous incarnate Murthien the Soul-Render, for all
>   his forays into the abomination that is necrocarnum, also
>   used dissolving spittle almost as a calling card. While this
>   meld is favored by chaotic and evil incarnates because of acid’s
>   association with both suffering and dissolution, incarnates of all alignments fi nd acidic spittle a useful weapon against
>   a variety of opponents.
>   **As a standard action, you can spit a glob of acid at a target
>   within 30 feet. This requires a ranged touch attack to hit
>   and deals 1d6 points of acid damage.** Using dissolving spittle
>   provokes attacks of opportunity.
>   Essentia: Every point of essentia you invest in your dissolving
>   spittle increases the damage dealt by 1d6 points.

So it don't.

Concerning the Rod, it says, when referring to enlarge :

> ENLARGE SPELL [METAMAGIC]
>   Benefit: You can alter a spell with a range of close, medium, or long to increase its range by 100%. An enlarged spell with a range of close now has a range of 50 ft. + 5 ft./level, while medium-range spells have a range of 200 ft. + 20 ft./level and long-range spells have a range of 800 ft. + 80 ft./level. An enlarged spell uses up a spell slot one level higher than the spell’s actual level.

Spells whose ranges are not defined by distance, as well as spells whose ranges are not close, medium, or long, do not have increased ranges.

Since soulmelds  :

> Soulmelds interact with spells and spells interact with soulmelds in the same way that a spell or a normal spell-like ability interacts with another spell or spell-like ability," and, "Spells, spell-like abilities, and magic items that could potentially affect soulmelds do affect soulmelds.

I think it would work, RAW.

I would not allow him to have an item which is less expensive than the rod of enlarge, out of balance : you need to compare items of equal power and their price should be comparable. If not, why would that item be created or bought? They become useless.

IF it doesn't make him stronger than a comparable class, it should be acceptable. Most spellcasting class can many good spells at long range...

Comment: Thank you. That's a solid close read of both those items. Heck, now—after looking at it in your answer—I don't think the *rod* would work with the *spittle* with it's flat 30-ft. range.  Which sucks for Jalas, I guess. No suggestions on other ways that might increase the *spittle* range?

Comment: You are right. Sadly no, I don't know any. I would recommend creating a custom item, with a quest, for fun purposes and accomplishment sense. Is it broken if it has more range? I don't think so. Price it according to the rod, or more. It could be nice treasure.